# Create generic List<T> of T4 generated type

Tags: c#, list, generics, t4

I created simple class using T4 technology.

```
<#@ template debug="false" hostspecific="false" language="C#" #>
<#@ output extension=".cs" #>
using System;

<# var properties = new String[]{"P1", "P2", "P3"}; #>
public class MyGeneratedClass {
<#  
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
    #>
        private Int32 _<#= properties[i] #> = <#= i #>;
        public Int32 <#= properties[i] #> 
        {
            get 
            {
                return _<#= properties[i] #>;
            }
        } 
    <#
    }
    #>
}
```

then I created an instance of that generated type like this

```
static void Main(String[] args)
{
    var template = new Template1();
    var text = template.TransformText();

    CodeDomProvider codeProvider = new CSharpCodeProvider();
    ICodeCompiler compiler = codeProvider.CreateCompiler();

    // add compiler parameters
    var compilerParams = new CompilerParameters
    {
        CompilerOptions = "/target:library /optimize",
        GenerateExecutable = false,
        GenerateInMemory = true,
        IncludeDebugInformation = false
    };
    compilerParams.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("mscorlib.dll");
    compilerParams.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.dll");

    // compile the code
    var compilerResults = compiler.CompileAssemblyFromSource(compilerParams, text);

    if (compilerResults.Errors.HasErrors)
        throw new Exception();

    // Создаем экземпляр класса
    var instance = compilerResults.CompiledAssembly.CreateInstance("MyGeneratedClass");
    if (instance == null)
        return;

    var TYPE = instance.GetType();
    var list = new List<TYPE>(); 

}
```

`var list = new List<TYPE>();` generate compile time error:

> *The type or namespace name 'TYPE' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)*

1. Is there any way to create generic list (or some generic collection) with the type of `MyGeneratedClass` class?
2. And is there simpler way to create instance of `MyGeneratedClass` class?

Comment: What is the point of using a generic list if the type of the list items is only known at runtime ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Type genericListType = typeof(List<>);
Type[] typeArgs = new[] { instance.GetType() };
var generic = genericListType.MakeGenericType(typeArgs);
System.Collections.IList list = (System.Collections.IList)Activator.CreateInstance(generic);

foreach (dynamic item in list)
{
//whatever
}
```

Hope i got you right..

EDIT something more usable,

This approach has not much advantages to a **ArrayList** just there are Exceptions at runtime if you try to add something different then the specific runtime type. While **ArrayList** will not throw an exception in the case the "wrong" item is added instead there will or will not be an exception if you use the items. I do (even if i don't know the Type at compile time) try to use the concrete generic instead of an open **ArrayList**, because the exception is raised at the right codeline (IMHO).

Comment: hmm, list now is Object type. And how can I use list as actually generic list? For example, add some item, or use foreach cycle? I cannot use explicit conversation like (List<???>)list...

Comment: list is of type List<YourRuntimeType> but as it is a runtime type it is not there at compile time. Allthought you can cast it to List or IEnumerable (not the generic ones). and insert items / use in foreach.